# Formatting Text Data Stored in SQLite3

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, sqlite, ios

I have paragraphs stored in SQLite cells, of which I wish to make a few important words **bold-face**. I take it I must make this formatting while entering the data into the database; how do I accomplish this? Also, when retrieving the data in Objective-C, how do I ensure it retains its formatting (programmatically) for use in a UITextView?

Edit: So not necessarily UITextView, but whatever works to display formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

UITextViews do not handle formatting styles.

The only way to show styles is to display using a UIWebView and using markup (bold tags for instance sometext)

At the same time you can save the marked up text in your SQLIte DB as normal.